# Rails 4: Loading posts w/ JQuery & AJAX on a "Load More" button

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a collection of Ideas (you can think of them as posts), and I want to display 6 on my index page initially, then have 6 more load whenever the user hits the "Load more" button. Here's my code:

`ideas_controller.rb`: (Index action)

```
# Get ideas that were created most recently
@ideas = Idea.page(params[:page]).per(6).order('created_at DESC')
```

Ideas index view:

```
.ordered-ideas
  = render @ideas
= link_to_next_page @ideas, 'Load More', :remote => true, :id =>"load_more_link"
```

`_idea.html.haml` (Partial):

```
%ul{ :class => 'span4' }
  %a{ :href => idea_path(idea.id), :class => 'thumbnail', :id => "idea_#{idea.id}" }
    .idea-concept-index
      = idea.concept

    .idea-description-index
      = idea.description
    %hr

    .idea-index-icons
      .idea-index-teams
        %i{ :class => 'fa fa-wrench' }
        = idea.teams.count
        teams

      .idea-index-like
        %i{ :class => 'fa fa-heart pink' }
        = idea.likes.count 
        likes
```

`index.js.erb`:

```
$('.ordered-ideas').append("<%=j render @ideas %>");
```

However, when I hit "Load more", nothing happens... what do I need to add? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you will need is pagination, since you haven't mentioned what library you are using. I am going to show how to do this with [`will_paginate`](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate).

#### Step 1: Add `gem will_paginate` to your Gemfile & run bundle.

#### Step 2: Use pagination:

```
@ideas = Idea.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 6).order(created_at: :desc)
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js
end
```

#### Step 3: View integration:

```
<div id="ordered-ideas">
  <%= render @ideas %>
</div>

<div id="infinite-scrolling">
  <%= will_paginate @ideas %>
</div>
```

_idea.html.haml (Partial):

```
%ul{ :class => 'span4' }
  %a{ :href => idea_path(idea.id), :class => 'thumbnail', :id => "idea_#{idea.id}" }
    .idea-concept-index
      = idea.concept

    .idea-description-index
      = idea.description
    %hr

    .idea-index-icons
      .idea-index-teams
        %i{ :class => 'fa fa-wrench' }
        = idea.teams.count
        teams

      .idea-index-like
        %i{ :class => 'fa fa-heart pink' }
        = idea.likes.count 
        likes
```

#### Step 4: Infinite Scrolling

Create a new file `pagination.js.coffee` inside the javascripts directory.

```
jQuery ->
  if $('#infinite-scrolling').size() > 0
    $(window).on 'scroll', ->
      more_ideas_url = $('.pagination .next_page a').attr('href')
        if more_posts_url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 60
            $('.pagination').html('<img src="/assets/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." title="Loading..." />')
            $.getScript more_ideas_url
        return
      return
```

The last thing to do is to create a view that will be rendered when responding with JS:

`index.js.erb`

```
$('#ordered-ideas').append('<%= j render @ideas %>');
<% if @ideas.next_page %>
  $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate @ideas %>');
<% else %>
  $(window).off('scroll');
  $('.pagination').remove();
```

if you have done everything till here correctly, your "load more" should be working. if not, then post with the code & error. so we can help you further.

Comment: Thanks. However, it seems as though the above code is for infinite scrolling, and for loading more ideas when the user has scrolled to the bottom of the page -- I'm simply trying to implement a "Load More" button, and am a bit confused as to how to modify the above code to do so.

Comment: Modify your jquery code to load more ideas on click of 'load more' button instead of `$(window).on 'scroll'`